# How to handle an enter pressed key android

Tags: android, search, keyboard, android-edittext, swipe

I am developing an app for an on-line store. One of the main feature is the search functionality. As I need to support API 8 and above instead of the `SearchView` I have used an `EditText` like below to implement the search view.

```
                <EditText android:id="@+id/search_edit"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/search_button"
                        android:background="@color/white"
                        android:ems="20"
                        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textColorHint="@color/ebuy_color_second_strip"
                        android:textSize="18sp" >
                    </EditText>
```

Now I want to handle the enter key of the keyboard, in a way than when the user press enter, the search activity begins. The code that I have used is like below:

```
search = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_edit);
        search.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                        && (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {

                    String query_text = search.getText().toString().trim();

                    try {
                        query_text = URLEncoder.encode(query_text, "utf-8");
                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {

                    }
                    String full_query = query_text;

                    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(search.getWindowToken(), 0);

                        Intent bussiness = new Intent(EbuyHomeScreen.this,
                                EbuySearchActivity.class);
                        Bundle basket_buss_category = new Bundle();

                        basket_buss_category.putString(EbuyUtils.TAG_CATEGORY_CODE, full_query);

                        bussiness.putExtras(basket_buss_category);

                        startActivity(bussiness);

                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }

        });
```

This way works perfectly good with android keyboard and some other keyboards, but when I use swipe or swift keyboard and other personalized keyboards that are downloaded from Google Play Store this doesn't work , and instead of beginning the activity jumps in a new line. Can somebody help me solve this kind of issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try **setOnEditorActionListener** on your edittext.

```
editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
@Override
public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
    if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH) {
        //your code here
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
});
```

You need to set **imeAction** in your edittext's xml file:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextUsername"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="USERNAME"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:imeOptions="actionSearch" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

Comment: What about the XML part, should I change there too?

Comment: @Xhulio you dont need to change your xml

Comment: @Argument it doesn't work, I also changed from the IME_ACTION_SEARCH to IME_ACTION_DONE but still it doesn't work.